# how to merge specific changes(commit,file) not whole branch?

Tags: git

I am working on two branch one for test and one for production. So I don't want to merge both branch because if I merge two branch then it will also merge setup file for test and production which I don't want.

Please provide suggestion about how can I merge only new commit.

> Tried: git merge production

Comment: Add files that should not be commited to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

Git does not provide a way to merge only part of a branch. Git doesn't track files independently like CVS does, instead tracking the entire file hierarchy as part of a commit.

The proper way to handle the situation of multiple configurations in different environments is to create either multiple files, one for each environment, and then select the right one depending on the environment, or to create one templated configuration file and use the proper data for the template depending on the environment. The selection of the proper environment and the generation of the correct configuration file necessarily needs to be done as part of your build or test step.

So, for example, you could have three configuration files, `config/development`, `config/test`, and `config/production`, and then use some technique specific to your environment to figure out which one to use in a given situation.

You could also pass the configuration parameters in for production (and possibly other environments) via the environment, and provide scripts for development and test that set the proper environment for those environments.